# Basic awk program failing

Tags: awk

So, I'm trying to make an awk program for a school assignment. I've just started, so I thought before writing the program itself, I would practice a little bit. This is my practice program:

```
BEGIN {print "yo"}
```

I try to run it with this command:

```
awk -f awk1 sample
```

Where sample is just a text file containing some records that I want to process (for the actual assignment), and the computer just says this:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

I feel so utterly and incredibly dumb, but what am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, nothing seems to be wrong with the program!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the program. Check your `awk1` file again.

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away on its own, just by magic. I'm using my university's Unix cluster to run awk, via an SSH from my home machine, so I'm a little confused as to what happened. Sorry about all that!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {print "Hello, World!"}

and execute the script

```
./yourscriptname
```

this will print "Hello World"

second way is

awk -f scriptname

for the awk -f method you don't need to put #!/usr/bin/awk in your program.

i think you are executing it in a wrong way.

awk -f awk1 sample  (you can't have spaces awk1 sample, it should be a one word)

Answer (score 0):

You are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). I can tell because of that useless error message. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or install/use gawk. Never, every use old, broken awk as it is, well, old and broken.