# Why doesn't this line work properly?

Tags: awk

I have this line in my awk program. I've seen other examples of awk code that looks like this and it works. Mine doesn't.

```
($0 ~ name) {print "Match found"}
```

Where `name` is a previously defined string variable.

Comment: We need see a lot more of your script.  Does the script run without error?  Simply saying "doesn't work" won't get you any decent help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a homework assignment, and my university's honor code prevents me from showing you my code and asking for your help. Sorry about that.

Comment: Good luck - I can't help you very much. The code you show is a special construct that is used outside of the main {} part of the code, like BEGIN{} and END{}.  It is an if (condition) then do {stuff here}

Comment: I know that. It's a pattern. My question is why the pattern causes the code to crash.

Comment: Last comment: if you are using gawk , there is a degugger for gawk (GNU) awk.  Try that.  My crystal ball is broken right now.  -> -> http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Debugger.html

Comment: What you posted will not cause your program to crash, it will simply compare each record to the variable `name` as an RE and, if they match, print the desired message. If your program is crashing, the issue is elsewhere in your code. If you can't post the rest of the code, we can't help you furhter.

Comment: I guess you need `$0 ~ /name/ {print "Match found"}`.

Comment: @neevek definitely not. That would compare $0 to a constant RE with value `name` instead of comparing $0 with the string stored in the variable `name` as an RE.

Answer (score 0):

From [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276194/basic-awk-program-failing) - you are using old, broken awk so anything could happen. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk or gawk or any other modern awk.